# Systematically moving through every number in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a 500x500 array and I am trying to write a variable called "coordinate" that will pick out each value and then apply it to a function but I keep getting the output,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/graham/<ipython-input-17-cc6ce0649eda> in <module>()
     31                         pass
     32 
---> 33 finished_array = rand_array_color(rand_array)
     34 
     35 finished_image = Image.fromarray(finished_array)

/home/graham/<ipython-input-17-cc6ce0649eda> in rand_array_color(rand_array)
     23         from PIL import Image
     24         for ii in numpy.nditer(rand_array):
---> 25                 coordinate = tuple(map(int, rand_image[ii,:]))
     26                 if ii < 128:
     27                         print "false"

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
    510             new['data'] = self.tostring()
    511             return new
--> 512         raise AttributeError(name)
    513 
    514     ##

AttributeError: __getitem__
```

Here is my code

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import random

im = Image.open('/home/graham/Desktop/Experiment/gwarner/labeled_photos/photos/003030.png')

rand_array = numpy.random.randint(255, size=(500,500)).astype('uint8')

rand_image = Image.fromarray(rand_array)

def rand_array_color(rand_array):
    from PIL import Image
    for ii in numpy.nditer(rand_array):
        coordinate = tuple(map(int, rand_image[ii,:]))
        if ii < 128:
            newvalue = rand_image.putpixel(coordinate(a,ii), im.getpixel(coordinate(a,ii)))
            return newvalue
        else:
            pass

finished_array = rand_array_color(rand_array)
```

I've also been fiddling around with another version of coordinate,

```
coordinate = tuple(int(rand_array[ii,0]),int(rand_array[ii,1])
```

but it just returns,

```
NameError: name 'ii' is not defined
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix one of these or recommend another one that will work?

Comment: If we had the full traceback, not just "AttributeError: __getitem__" it would be easier to go directly to the problem. I suspect that it might be from the rand_image[ii, :] call?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot get the `ii`th row of `rand_image` using `rand_image[ii,:]` is because `rand_image` is a PIL Image object, and doesn't have the same indexing access that an array has.  If you want to get the `ii`th row, you must use `rand_array[ii]` (I've left off the trailing colon `,:` isn't required)

This appears to be similar to your

> another version of `coordinate`

which should work because you're using the array instead of the Image.  My guess is that you've not replaced it in *exactly* the same place as the first version, perhaps somewhere outside of the `for ii in ...` loop, because `ii` is only properly defined within that loop.

---

As you've defined it, `coordinate` is not a function, it's a tuple of length 2. But you call it as a function when you write `coordinate(a, ii)`.  Rather, you probably just want to use `coordinate` there (I'm not sure what `a` is supposed to be.

---

The function `.putpixel` does not return anything, so that when you say:

```
newvalue = rand_image.putpixel(...)
```

`newvalue` will be `None` (the 'empty' object in python).  Perhaps you want to do this:

```
rand_image.putpixel(...)
return rand_image
```

without setting the `newvalue` and trying to return it, but instead changing the pixel in the `rand_image` and returning the new `rand_image`.

---

As a side note, you should not call `int()` on a numpy array, instead, if you want the type of each element in the array to be `int`, you should either use `.astype` as you did above, or initiate it as an `int` in the first place.  Once it starts as an `int`, it should stay that way unless you cast it somehow (which you haven't done in this script).

---

As a final note this process could probably be done a *lot* faster using numpy (not using pure python loops) but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.  If you edit your question to explain a little bit what you're trying to do so that I can read the code with some context, I could help.  For example, what is `a` supposed to be in the `newvalue = ...` line?